# Why am I getting extra node contents from my DOM parser

Tags: java, parsing, dom

I want to get the text context from the `modules` nodes, but it returns extra values from the tree.

```
<modules>New Enterprise Development 
    <credits>15</credits>
    <level>M</level>   
    <core_or_optional>core</core_or_optional>
</modules>
<modules>Computing Law, Contracts and Professional Responsibility
    <credits>15</credits>
    <level>M</level>
    <core_or_optional>core</core_or_optional>
</modules>
```

parsing code:

```
for (int j=0; j<NodelistB.getLength(); j++){
    Node xPathNode = NodelistB.item(j);
    Element xPath = (Element)xPathNode;
    targetNodeContent = xPath.getTextContent();
    targetNode = xPath.getTagName();
    System.out.println(targetNodeContent) ; 
    System.out.println() ;      
}
```

I expected the return values to be:

```
New Enterprise Development
Computing Law, Contracts and Professional Responsibility
```

But it prints out the following:

```
New Enterprise Development 
15
M
core                 

Computing Law, Contracts and Professional Responsibility
15
M
core
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent%28%29) of `getTextContent()`:

> This attribute returns the text content of this node **and its descendants**.

Comment: So how can i get its first decendant?.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is not valid (or not as you think). You should use one of these formats:

```
<modules name="New Enterprise Development">
    <credits>15</credits>
    <level>M</level>   
    <core_or_optional>core</core_or_optional>
</modules>

<modules>
    <name>New Enterprise Development</name>
    <credits>15</credits>
    <level>M</level>   
    <core_or_optional>core</core_or_optional>
</modules>
```

(also, you should probably use 'module', not 'modules')